# PXE boot: TFTP file transfer fails

Tags: dhcp, pxe, tftp

I am trying to PXE boot from a Windows 2019 server running tftpd32, as installed by CloneDeploy 1.4.0. The server's firewall is disabled. When trying to PXE boot (ipxe), the clients get an IP through DCHP, and are able to connect to the TFTP server, but then transfer times out:

```
TFTP.
PXE-E35
PXE-E39
```

This setup had been working pre-Corona, but now no longer. I am a bit rusty on what may have changed since. I have updated my computer BIOS/UEFI, but that is not the issue I think as i meet the same trouble when PXE-booting another machine that i have not touched. Both booting through Intel NICs on multiple machines and through a QLogic NIC fails, same symptoms and log (see below). I have updated the pfsense version (separate box running DHCP server), but i don't see how that could affect things as the DHCP side of things seems to work fine?

Client and server are on the same subnet, with only a (definitely not overloaded) switch in between. Switch has no traffic restrictions defined on it.

I have locally booted a computer from which I tried to network boot. When running a TFTP client on this computer, i can download the file in question, `pxeboot.0` just fine.
This is the tftpd32 log of a failed boot attempt:

```
Connection received from 10.0.1.76 on port 2070 [21/08 09:20:14.219]
Read request for file <pxeboot.0>. Mode octet [21/08 09:20:14.219]
OACK: <tsize=67641,> [21/08 09:20:14.219]
Using local port 60476 [21/08 09:20:14.219]
Peer returns ERROR <TFTP Aborted> -> aborting transfer [21/08 09:20:14.219]
Connection received from 10.0.1.76 on port 2071 [21/08 09:20:14.219]
Read request for file <pxeboot.0>. Mode octet [21/08 09:20:14.219]
OACK: <blksize=1456,> [21/08 09:20:14.219]
Using local port 60477 [21/08 09:20:14.219]
Ack block 1 ignored (received twice) [21/08 09:20:16.235]
TIMEOUT waiting for Ack block #2  [21/08 09:20:34.279]
```

and here a log from a successful transfer using a tftp client when booted into Windows (also works with default blocksize, which removed that from the OACK):

```
Connection received from 10.0.1.36 on port 59131 [21/08 10:19:54.213]
Read request for file <pxeboot.0>. Mode octet [21/08 10:19:54.213]
OACK: <blksize=1024,tsize=67641,> [21/08 10:19:54.213]
Using local port 49403 [21/08 10:19:54.213]
<pxeboot.0>: sent 67 blks, 67641 bytes in 0 s. 0 blk resent [21/08 10:19:54.213]
```

I have tried changing the settings of tftpd32: tried all combinations of "option negotiation" and "PXE Compatibility" on and off, doesn't fix the problem.

What could i try to diagnose or fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I was able to also rule out this being the server, when installing tftpd32 on a different machine, i had the same trouble. I switched to OpenTFTPServer, which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already solved your problem.

You say the firewall on the Windows server is disabled, but there could still be one either on the client, or somewhere between the two systems. A NAT router would also cause the same problem.

TFTP is *not* firewall friendly (with or without NAT), because it only uses port 69 during the initial negotiation. During the data transfer, it instead uses random ports on *both* ends of the connection. Firewalls will usually block this traffic because they don't recognize the responses.

To solve this, any firewall (or NAT router) between the systems must be TFTP-aware; you usually need to enable a TFTP helper.

The difference between tftpd32 and opentftpserver may come down to how exactly they allocate the random port on the server side. According to the standards, it should be an ephemeral port, but apparently some implementations instead hardcode this random port. If that hardcoded port comes from a different address range, the client may reject it.

This is just speculation, though.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. There is no firewall in between, just a single dumb switch. It remains a head-scratcher, but will apply the "don't touch it as long as it works" strategy. I must have changed something at some point that caused tftpd32 to no longer work for me, just can't remember what...